# Symfony dependency injection and your own services

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am trying to register my own class as a services with help of symfony dependency injection component, but i have problems with class loading.

I have file structure as this:

[image]

My Generator class is simple

```
<?php

namespace Localhost\Service\String;

class Generator {

    private $iStringLength;

    public function __construct($iNewStringLength = 5) {
        $this->iStringLength = $iNewStringLength;
    }

    public function getRandomString() {
        $sChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $sRandChar = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($sChars,5)),0, $this->iStringLength);

        return $sRandChar;
    }
}
```

And Index is

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

/*
spl_autoload_register(function ($sClass) {
    echo $sClass;
    require_once str_replace('\\', '/', $sClass) . '.php';
});
*/

use Localhost\Service\String\Generator;

/*
$oStringGenerator = new Generator(55);
echo $oStringGenerator->getRandomString();
*/

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

$oContainer = new ContainerBuilder();
$oContainer
    ->register('generator', 'Generator')
    ->addArgument('15');

$oGeneratorService = $oContainer->get('generator');
echo $oGeneratorService->getRandomString();
```

What i am getting is an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Generator does not exist' in D:\Localhost\Apache\htdocs\Test\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php:959 Stack trace: #0 D:\Localhost\Apache\htdocs\Test\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php(959): ReflectionClass->__construct('Generator') #1 D:\Localhost\Apache\htdocs\Test\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php(493): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition), 'generator') #2 D:\Localhost\Apache\htdocs\Test\index.php(26): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('generator') #3 {main} thrown in D:\Localhost\Apache\htdocs\Test\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php on line 959
```

Or as a picture

[image]

Comment: This is symfony2 project? Or you wanna use only DependencyInjection Component?

Comment: Only DependencyInjection component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$oContainer = new ContainerBuilder();
$oContainer
    ->register('generator', 'Localhost\Service\String\Generator')
    ->addArgument('15');
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution is simple, i forgot to modify composer config to load my services

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"Localhost": "src/"}
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: **Since Symfony 3.3+** (May 2017) you can use `register()` class name service shortcut:

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->register(Localhost\Service\String\Generator::class)
    ->addArgument('15');
```

---

**Since PHP 5.5+** you can use more fail-proof `::class` notation:

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->register('generator', Localhost\Service\String\Generator::class)
    ->addArgument('15');
```

Now, when class name will be miss-typed, your IDE will highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

**addition**:

You should propbably [compile](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.html#method_compile) the container for performance reasons.

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container
    ->register('generator', 'Localhost\Service\String\Generator')
    ->addArgument('15')
;
$container->compile();
```

Comment: Now it generates fatal, "Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource' not found" :) But its understandable, i have no config component included.

Comment: Oh that's odd. I think it should probably throw a more descriptive exception in case `symfony/config` isn't installed.